# Records are not coming in textfile from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file, fwrite

Here, I want to fetch record from mysql to textfile that I am writing into textfile.
But textfile is creating as blank.
Where is the problem?

My code:

```
$myFile = 'abctest.txt';
//echo $myFile;exit;
$fo = fopen('com_order/order_textfile/'.$myFile, 'w+') or die("can't open file");

$data_query=mysql_query("SELECT order_id from tbl_order") or die(mysql_error());

while($data=mysql_fetch_array($data_query))
{
    $stringData = fwrite($fo, "Order: ".$data['order_id']."\n");
}
fwrite($fo, $stringData);
fclose($fo);

header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$myFile);
```

Comment: What is the output from `mysql_error()` if any?

Comment: No @TimBiegeleisen: Its shows nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*readfile()* call is missing:

```
readfile($myFile);
```

So it should look like this:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$myFile);
readfile($myFile);
```

Here readfile() is the function which actually performs all the hard work (reads the file, writes to output).

More on the topic:

[readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

[Force download](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/forcedownload.html)

**UPDATE**

Also you have a *file path* problem

Note that you create file in `com_order/order_textfile/'.$myFile` but then use $myFile without the path. When referencing file you should use path instead:

```
$myFile = 'abctest.txt';
$filePath = 'com_order/order_textfile/'.$myFile;
$fo = fopen($filePath, 'w+') or die("can't open file");

$data_query=mysql_query("SELECT order_id from tbl_order") or die(mysql_error());

while($data=mysql_fetch_array($data_query))
{
    $stringData = fwrite($fo, "Order: ".$data['order_id']."\n");
}
fwrite($fo, $stringData);
fclose($fo);

header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$filePath);
readfile($filePath);
```

Comment: Thanks, but No records are coming in textfile.. !!

Comment: Yeah...Now I get what I want...!! Thanks palovich.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a problem with the way you execute your query but try the code below it's working.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database name") or die("error unable to connect to database". mysqli_error($link)); 

$myFile = 'abctest.txt';
//echo $myFile;exit;
$fo = fopen('com_order/order_textfile/'.$myFile, 'w+') or die("can't open file");

$data_query=$link->query("SELECT order_id from tbl_order") or die(mysql_error());

while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($data_query))
{
    $stringData = fwrite($fo, "Order: ".$data['order_id']."\n");
    //echo("$stringData");
}
fwrite($fo, $stringData);
fclose($fo);

header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$myFile);
```

Comment: Thanks, but No records are coming in textfile.. !!

Comment: Make sure the following is correct 1) directory to your text file 2) query.